# Nodejs addon static library link: missing symbols

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, boost, node.js-addon

Its been a few years since I've done some C++ development.  I'm trying to statically link the boost regex library and I'm getting the following errors when running

> node addon.js

(i'm using the node-addon-examples/2_function_arguments example)

```
 node addon.js
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN5boost16re_detail_10600012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE14construct_initERKNS_11basic_regexIcSD_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE
  Referenced from: /Users/sjoseph/code/nodejs/addons/node-addon-examples/2_function_arguments/boost/build/Release/addon.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN5boost16re_detail_10600012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE14construct_initERKNS_11basic_regexIcSD_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE
  Referenced from: /Users/sjoseph/code/nodejs/addons/node-addon-examples/2_function_arguments/boost/build/Release/addon.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I'm on macosx

```
nodejs: v4.3.0
 g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

binding.gyp:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ "addon.cc" ],
      "include_dirs":[
        "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0/include"
        ],
      "link_settings":{
        "libraries":[
        "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0/lib/libboost_regex.a"
        ],
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

addon.cc

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <node.h>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using std::string;
using namespace std;
using namespace v8;

void Add(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  if (args.Length() < 2) {
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong number of arguments")));
    return;
  }

  if (!args[0]->IsNumber() || !args[1]->IsNumber()) {
    isolate->ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong arguments")));
    return;
  }

  double value = args[0]->NumberValue() + args[1]->NumberValue();
  Local<Number> num = Number::New(isolate, value);

  args.GetReturnValue().Set(num);

std::string s = "Boost Libraries";
  boost::regex expr{"(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)"};
  boost::smatch what;
  if (boost::regex_search(s, what, expr))
  {
    std::cout << what[0] << '\n';
    std::cout << what[1] << "_" << what[2] << '\n';
  } 
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "add", Add);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

addon.js

```
var addon = require('bindings')('addon.node')

console.log('This should be eight:', addon.add(3, 5))
```

Note: dynamically linking the library also causes problems.

Question: Do I need to compile nodejs & boost using the same compiler?